# Getting other fields after using MAX PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an `orders` table that has a primary key `id` column, an `order_id` column, and a `created_date` column:

```
===================================
              ORDERS
===================================

id | order_id |    created_date
-----------------------------------
 1 |   178    | 2022-11-16 09:25:11
 2 |   182    | 2022-11-18 08:44:19
 3 |   178    | 2022-11-17 11:16:22
 4 |   178    | 2022-11-18 14:55:41
 5 |   195    | 2022-11-15 09:11:17
 6 |   195    | 2022-11-16 21:22:32
 7 |   146    | 2022-11-16 16:55:09
 8 |   178    | 2022-11-16 04:39:16
 9 |   121    | 2022-11-16 01:20:19
```

I want to write a query that returns the highest `created_date` for a specific `order_id`, so I'm trying to use `MAX()`. But I would also like to return the `id` of that highest `created_date` row. In the example above, let's say that I would like to return the row that fits this criteria for order ID 178:

```
SELECT   MAX(o.created_date),
         o.id
FROM     orders o
WHERE    o.order_id = 178
GROUP BY o.id;
```

The problem is that when I write the query like this, I get multiple rows returned. I've tried removing the `GROUP BY` altogether but aside from that, I cannot wrap my head around what I would need to do to this query to show the following information:

`4 | 2022-11-18 14:55:41`

How can I write a PostgreSQL query to show the row with the highest `created_date` value but also show other information for that row?

Comment: What kind of timestamp is this :) `2022-11-16 04:39:76`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to use `distinct on`, and get the max value by `order by desc` instead of `max`.  Something like this:

```
select distinct on (order_id) id, order_id, created_date
from orders
order by order_id, created_date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a CTE to calculate which is the latest `order_id` by using `ROW_NUMBER()` and the correct `ORDER BY`. After that, select the entire row using this pseudo-ranker.

```
WITH ranked_order_ids_by_date AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS date_rank
  FROM USERS
)
SELECT *
FROM ranked_order_ids_by_date
WHERE order_id = 178
  AND date_rank = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sH2Q38zR)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about multiple order_id's having the identic latest date, you can just use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT id, order_id, created_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_id = 178
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If different order id's can appear and you want to get all of them, in Postgres DB's, you can use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES` (thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for that hint!):

```
SELECT id, order_id, created_date
FROM orders
WHERE order_id = 178
ORDER BY created_date DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

As a more general way, you could also use a window function, for a example `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH o AS
(
 SELECT orders.*, DENSE_RANK() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date DESC) AS sub
   FROM orders
  WHERE order_id = 178
)
SELECT id, order_id, created_date
  FROM o
 WHERE sub = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement with sub-selects if you don't want to use CTE:

```
SELECT 
id,
order_id,
max(case when us.d_rank = 1 then us.created_date else null end) as max_created
FROM  (
            SELECT 
            created_date,
            order_id,
            dense_rank() over (partition by order_id order by created_date DESC) d_rank
            FROM users
        ) us 
 WHERE us.order_id = 178
```